# Adobe Air - Dispatch event with parameter

Tags: actionscript-3, air, dispatchevent

How to pass the *addChild(event.target.loader)* through a dispatch event from the class to the main timeline?

```
 package scraps
    {
    ...
    public class FileScrap extends Scrap
        {
    ...
     private function loadImage(event:Event):void{
                    addChild(event.target.loader);  
            }
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean? Sharing a bit more of you code would be helpful. However if I do get what your trying to ask then what you looking for is this `addChild((event.target as LoaderInfo).loader);`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom event class that extends flash.events.Event and have the DisplayObject that gets loaded sent as a property of that event. In that case FileScrap will need to inherit from EventDispatcher or implement IEventDispatcher.

You could also just dispatch a generic event called IMAGE_LOADED or something like that, and have the main class poll a public method in scraps to get the image whenever it receives the event.